# Alternative SQL Compliant DB to sqlite

Tags: in-memory-database, embedded-database

I am writing an application in C#.NET. I need to use a SQL compliant single file db like sqlite. I can't use sqlite because it is extremely odd way of storing dates in UTC instead of localtime. Also its support for date operations relies on Julianized date format which is not easy for end-user to grasp at all.

I wish I could use MS-Access, but I guess the end user will have to have MS-Access on their machine to run the application, which is not something I can ask them for.

It is important for me to have near zero install experience.

I took a look at H2 but I am not sure how easy it is to run with .NET and I did not see any browser for it.

The database is expected to be used by 5 users at most for read and 1 user for write at any given time. The largest volume may not exceed 100000 rows in 5 tables.

I would like the solution to be royalty free, even if the product itself is not free.

Thank you.

Comment: "`I can't use sqlite because it is extremely odd way of storing dates in UTC instead of localtime`" == "`I ***won't*** use sqlite because it is extremely odd way of storing dates in UTC instead of localtime`". You can use it, just don't want to. "`Julianized date format which is not easy for end-user to grasp at all`" which is why your GUI translates it for them.

Comment: @Mawg, Thanks for your comment. I can't use it because I find it very hard to use. Which GUI tool automatically does the translation? In my application, I want users to use simple SELECT statements. I need to spend time and effort to take care of the translation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for your suggestion, I will give it a try. If you like you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/) a try.

It is a very capable relational database, that can be used in embedded mode ("single file"). It's the embedded DBMS used by the newer versions of LibreOffice.

It can also be used as a central database server installation in case youneed that later.

It offers much better data type handling than SQLite (which essentially doesn't have anything else than string) - including a proper [timestamp](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html) (although without time zone support)